# How do you add rows that have NA as prior columns in R?

Tags: r, sum, lag, shift

All,

I have a dataframe with Dates on the first column and categories across as such:

```
Accounts <- c('A','B','C','D',
          'A','B','C','D',
          'A','B','C','D')
Dates <- as.Date(c('2016-01-31', '2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-01-31',
               '2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28',
               '2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31'))
Balances <- c(100,NA,NA,NA,
          90,50,10,NA,
          80,40,5,120)
Origination <- data.frame(Dates,Accounts,Balances)

library(reshape2)
Origination <- dcast(Origination,Dates ~ Accounts, value.var = "Balances")

       Dates   A  B  C   D
1 2016-01-31 100 NA NA  NA
2 2016-02-28  90 50 10  NA
3 2016-03-31  80 40  5 120
```

The goal is to sum rows where the prior values is NA.  I tried to used lag or shift but don't have the knowledge to pull it off.

So for this dataframe I would like a Totals column at the end it values 60 (50 + 10) and 120 for February and March.

Is this doable?

Regards,
Aksel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift the selection down a row, filter out all the non-NA's as 0, and then use `rowSums`:

```
sel <- rbind(FALSE, !is.na(head(Origination[-1], -1)))
#sel
#         A     B     C     D
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

rowSums(replace(Origination[-1], sel, 0), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 100  60 120
```

If you want the first row to be totally excluded, rather than totally included, just change the `FALSE` to `TRUE`:

```
sel <- rbind(TRUE, !is.na(head(Origination[-1], -1)))
rowSums(replace(Origination[-1], sel, 0), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1]   0  60 120
```

Comment: Brilliant! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

thelatemail's solution looks great.

however, if you want to avoid printing total value of January, try this

```
Origination.matrix.select<-rbind(F,is.na(Origination[-1]))[-4,]
Total<-rowSums(as.matrix(Origination[,2:5])*Origination.matrix.select,na.rm=T)
Total
# [1] 0 60 120
```

Comment: Actually, you answered what I was looking for initially, but thelatemail's solution was what I was ultimately after. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to continue the chain form `reshape2::dcast` and use `dplyr::mutate_at` to find desired output.

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(reshape2)
  Origination %>% 
    dcast(Dates~Accounts, value.var = "Balances" ) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(c("A","B","C","D")), 
          funs(ifelse(!is.na(lag(.)), NA, (.)))) %>%
    mutate(sum = rowSums(select(.,-Dates), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    select(Dates, sum)      
  # Dates         sum
  # 1 2016-01-31  100
  # 2 2016-02-28   60
  # 3 2016-03-31  120
```

Note: `row_number()==1` condition should be added part of `ifelse` in `mutate_at` if sum for `January` is expected as `0`.

**Data**

```
  Accounts <- c('A','B','C','D',
                'A','B','C','D',
                'A','B','C','D')
  Dates <- as.Date(c('2016-01-31', '2016-01-31','2016-01-31','2016-01-31',
                     '2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28','2016-02-28',
                     '2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31','2016-03-31'))
  Balances <- c(100,NA,NA,NA,
                90,50,10,NA,
                80,40,5,120)
  Origination <- data.frame(Dates,Accounts,Balances)
```